# unable to read one number, print out an output then then move on to the next number in VB

Tags: vb.net

im trying to make a code that a user can enter a number, then the code will read the first number, then speak the output. it will move to the next number. however it will only do the first number and will do it for how many numbers have been entered in.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnSpeak_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSpeak.Click
        Dim number As String = Convert.ToInt32(Char.GetNumericValue(txtNumber.Text))
        Dim x, y As Integer
        Dim numb1 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Len(txtNumber.Text))
        Dim numb2 As Integer = 0
        Dim test As Integer



        x = 0
        y = 30000.01

        If number < x Then
            MsgBox("error")
        Else
            If number > y Then
                MsgBox("error")
            Else

                Do Until numb2 = numb1


                    If number = 9 Then
                        My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\Computing Year 1\Nick\Unit 16 - Client Side Customisation of Webpages\In Progress\16.3\Audio clips\Nine.wav")
                        numb2 = numb2 + 1
                    ElseIf number = 8 Then
                        My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\Computing Year 1\Nick\Unit 16 - Client Side Customisation of Webpages\In Progress\16.3\Audio clips\Eight.wav")
                        numb2 += 1
                    ElseIf number = 7 Then
                        My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\Computing Year 1\Nick\Unit 16 - Client Side Customisation of Webpages\In Progress\16.3\Audio clips\Seven.wav")
                        numb2 += 1
                    ElseIf number = 6 Then
                        My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\Computing Year 1\Nick\Unit 16 - Client Side Customisation of Webpages\In Progress\16.3\Audio clips\Six.wav")
                        numb2 += 1
                    ElseIf number = 5 Then
                        My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\Computing Year 1\Nick\Unit 16 - Client Side Customisation of Webpages\In Progress\16.3\Audio clips\Five.wav")
                        numb2 += 1
                    ElseIf number = 4 Then
                        My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\Computing Year 1\Nick\Unit 16 - Client Side Customisation of Webpages\In Progress\16.3\Audio clips\Four.wav")
                        numb2 += 1
                    ElseIf number = 3 Then
                        My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\Computing Year 1\Nick\Unit 16 - Client Side Customisation of Webpages\In Progress\16.3\Audio clips\Three.wav")
                        numb2 += 1
                    ElseIf number = 2 Then
                        My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\Computing Year 1\Nick\Unit 16 - Client Side Customisation of Webpages\In Progress\16.3\Audio clips\Two.wav")
                        numb2 += 1
                    ElseIf number = 1 Then
                        My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\Computing Year 1\Nick\Unit 16 - Client Side Customisation of Webpages\In Progress\16.3\Audio clips\One.wav")
                        numb2 += 1
                    ElseIf number = 0 Then
                        My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\Computing Year 1\Nick\Unit 16 - Client Side Customisation of Webpages\In Progress\16.3\Audio clips\Zero.wav")
                        numb2 += 1
                    ElseIf number = (".") Then
                        My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\Computing Year 1\Nick\Unit 16 - Client Side Customisation of Webpages\In Progress\16.3\Audio clips\Point.wav")
                        numb2 += 1
                    End If
                    MsgBox("test")
                Loop
                MsgBox("tester")
                Close()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

if you enter in 1234 it should say 1234
but it says 1111

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: ` y = 30000.01`  will give an error with Option Strict on because that number is NOT an Integer.

Comment: `If number < x Then` You are comparing a number to a string. This can have unexpected results. It would be flagged with Option Strict ON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [Char.GetNumericValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Char_GetNumericValue_System_Char_) with just a string passed as parameter returns the numeric value of the first char in that string. If you you want to *GetNumericValue* of the second character inside a string you need to give the position of that character inside the string and because the index into arrays start at value zero, the second position is 1.

Of course you need to have this logic applied inside the Do Until loop where you can change the index to pass at GetNumeriCalue at each loop.

```
     Dim numb2 As Integer = 0
     Dim numb1 As Integer = txtNumber.Text.Length

     Do Until numb2 = numb1
        ' We want to get the value at the current loop position
        number = Convert.ToInt32(Char.GetNumeriValue(txtNumber.Text, numb2))
        If number = 9 Then
            ... the whole if elseif sequence follows with numb1 increments
        End if
     Loop
```

Consider also that you should add a check to understand if the user really types something that contains only numbers because Char.GetNumericValue of a character not a number will return -1, for example you could add this at the start of your button click

```
   If Not Int32.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, number) Then
      MessageBox.Show("Type only numbers please!")
      Return
   End If
```

Comment: i have added this into my code and now its working, however if the user enters in a decimal place it wont register it as one

Comment: Of course, if you want to handle decimal numbers then you should change everything to decimal. Convert.ToDecimal, Decimal.TryParse. declare decimal variables etc...

Comment: And you should check if the character is the decimal separator because you cannot assign a point to an integer or decimal variable.  _If txtNumber.Text(numb2) = '.' Then_ before trying to use the number returned by GetNumericValue

Comment: I received an error from `Char.GetNumericValue(txtNumber.Text` with option strict on. Cannot convert String to Char. The OP would have saved himself some trouble if he was coding with Option Strict ON.

Answer (score 0):

A string is not only a String but an array of Char. You can use this to your advantage in this code. Loop through each Char in the array of Char that is a string. The cases are in double quotes like a string only followed with a lower case c to tell the compiler that this is a Char. In C# we would use single quotes around the character but vb uses the single quote for the comment character. (Not relevant, just trivia) No conversions, no incrementing a counter.

```
Private Sub btnSpeak_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSpeak.Click
    For Each ch As Char In TextBox1.Text
        Select Case ch
            Case "9"c
                My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\Computing Year 1\Nick\Unit 16 - Client Side Customisation of Webpages\In Progress\16.3\Audio clips\Nine.wav")
            Case "8"c
                My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\Computing Year 1\Nick\Unit 16 - Client Side Customisation of Webpages\In Progress\16.3\Audio clips\Eight.wav")
                'And the rest of the cases
            Case Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numeric characters")
                Exit Sub
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Another approach - rename your files 9.wav, 8.wav, 7.wav. It won't work for the period. You would have to check for "."c and .Play the Point.wav.

```
Private Sub ReadNumbers()
    For Each ch As Char In TextBox1.Text
        If ch = "."c Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\Computing Year 1\Nick\Unit 16 - Client Side Customisation of Webpages\In Progress\16.3\Audio clips\Point.wav")
        Else
            My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\Computing Year 1\Nick\Unit 16 - Client Side Customisation of Webpages\In Progress\16.3\Audio clips\" & ch & ".wav")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```